# Python: Email problem

Tags: python, email

I'm using the script below to send an email to myself, the script runs fine with no errors but I don't physically receive an email.

```
import smtplib

sender = 'foo@hotmail.com'
receivers = ['foo@hotmail.com']

message = """From: From Person <foo@hotmail.com>
To: To Person <foo@hotmail.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

---

EDIT

The script is named `test.py`

Comment: If I ever physically received an email, I'd have to have a talk with my shrink.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you use localhost as the SMTP?

If you are using hotmail you need to use hotmail account, provide the password, enter port and SMTP server etc.

Here is everything you need:
http://techblissonline.com/hotmail-pop3-and-smtp-settings/

edit:
Here is a example if you use gmail:

```
def mail(to, subject, text):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = gmail_user
    msg['To'] = to
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    Encoders.encode_base64(part)
    msg.attach(part)

    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.starttls()
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
    mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
    # Should be mailServer.quit(), but that crashes...
    mailServer.close()
```

Comment: I receive a NameError: Multipart is not defined

Comment: @Phil Have you imported it correctly?
 from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the import

Answer (score 2):

I have something to add to Klark's great answer. When I try:

```
Encoders.encode_base64(part)
```

I received an error

```
NameError: global name 'Encoders' is not defined
```

It should be

```
encoders.encode_base64(msg)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Atwood's [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) from last April may be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

The "localhost" SMTP server won't work with Hotmail. You'll have to hard-code your password in so Hotmail can authenticate you as well. The default SMTP for Hotmail is "smtp.live.com" on port 25. Try:

```
import smtplib

sender = 'foo@hotmail.com'
receivers = ['foo@hotmail.com']
password = 'your email password'

message = """From: From Person <foo@hotmail.com>
To: To Person <foo@hotmail.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.live.com",25)
   smtpObj.ehlo()
   smtpObj.starttls()
   smtpObj.ehlo()
   smtpObj.login(sender, password)
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```